# How to append/remove attribute value on click to/from the comma separated list within hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of colors as list items within unordered list. I want list item attribute value to be added to my hidden input in the form of a comma separated list (e.g. red,blue,green) upon click.   When value is already present in the list, I want it to be removed from there.  Here is what I have done so far.

```
<ul>
  <li class="colors" data-color="red" id="red">RED</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="blue" id="blue">BLUE</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="green" id="green">GREEN</li>
</ul>

<input type="hidden" id="colorvalues" name="colorvalues" value="">
```

Here is the jQuery.

```
 $('.colors').toggle(function() {
  var color = $(this).data('color');

  $("#colorvalues").val(function() {
    return this.value + color;
  });

  $(this.id).addClass('selected');

}, function() {
  var color = $(this).data('color');

  $("#colorvalues").val(function() {
    return this.value - color;
  });

  $(this.id).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something, like that?:

```js
var selectedColors = [];
$('.colors').on('click', function () {
 const clickedColor = $(this).attr('data-color');
 selectedColors = selectedColors.includes(clickedColor) ? selectedColors.filter(color => color != clickedColor) : [...selectedColors, clickedColor];
 $('#colorvalues').val(selectedColors.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colors" data-color="red" id="red">RED</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="blue" id="blue">BLUE</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="green" id="green">GREEN</li>
</ul>
<input id="colorvalues" name="colorvalues" value="">
```

Comment: Copied this code over as is, but getting random instances where there will be two commas instead of one.  Can't quite pinpoint what is doing this?  Otherwise working well.  Any thoughts on what could be causing it?

Comment: just amazing ;)

Comment: @CRAIG: MS browser?

Comment: @user11299053 no, using Chrome on OSX

Comment: the console log for the selectedColors array after I click on red is showing this: (2) ["red", undefined] so an undefined variable is sneaking in there somehow.

Comment: @CRAIG : Tried to reproduce your issue in different browsers (including Chrome 72, on Windows, though). The code works just fine. Taking into account, you've faced the same issue with another answer, I may assume, it's most probably some part of your code (some loops, other click handlers, etc), hard to say for sure without seeing the rest of the context.

Comment: Thanks @user11299053.  I ended up getting it working by having it remove any extra commas after the fact.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

[`jQuery#toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is used for display or hide the matched element, if I am not wrong.

You have to add a `click` event listener on your list's elements, then check inside if your hidden input's value already contains the clicked element's `color` data value.

In function of that, add or remove that value to/from your input one.

Here's a basic example:

```js
$('.colors').on('click', function() {
  const jHidden = $('#colorvalues'),
    chosenColor = $(this).data('color');
  
  // Converts to array, because array manipulation is much easier.
  let colors = (jHidden.val()) ? jHidden.val().split(',') : [];
  
  // If the clicked color is found, remove it from the array.
  if (colors.includes(chosenColor)) {
    colors.splice(colors.indexOf(chosenColor), 1);
  } // If not, add it to the array.
  else {
    colors.push(chosenColor);
  }
  
  // Re-converts it to a string, then affects it to the hidden input.
  jHidden.val(colors.join(','));
  
  console.log(`hidden input's value =`, jHidden.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colors" data-color="red" id="red">RED</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="blue" id="blue">BLUE</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="green" id="green">GREEN</li>
</ul>

<input type="hidden" id="colorvalues" name="colorvalues" value="">
```

Comment: Huh, I thought toggle added a click handler by default.  Ok cool.  This seems to work great, but for some reason, on my end, it is adding an extra comma to each value.  Trying to sort that out.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.colors').on('click',function() {
      var color = $(this).data('color');
      if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        // add value if is not selected class
        $('#colorvalues').val(
        $('#colorvalues').val() === "" ? 
        color :
        $('#colorvalues').val() + ',' + color
        );
        $(this).addClass('selected');
      } else {
        let value = '';
        if ($('#colorvalues').val() === color) {
          value = '';
        } else if ($('#colorvalues').val().search(color) === 0) {
          value = $('#colorvalues').val().replace(color + ',', '');
        } else {
          value = $('#colorvalues').val().replace(',' + color, '')
        }
        
        $('#colorvalues').val(value);
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      }

      console.log($('#colorvalues').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="colors" data-color="red" id="red">RED</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="blue" id="blue">BLUE</li>
  <li class="colors" data-color="green" id="green">GREEN</li>
</ul>

<input type="hidden" id="colorvalues" name="colorvalues" value="">
```

thanks